# Find primitive of $\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{x}+(x-a)}$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

How do I find a primitive of this function ($a$ is a constant)?

Comment: Primitive means integrate , try substituting $x=\sin^{2}t$ and then after simplification put $sint =u$

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. It is here mandatory to show some effort. What are your own thoughts?

Comment: @SujithZis Isn't that equivalent to just set $x=u^2$?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut oopse didn't clearly think it out , sorry

Comment: This innocent looking integral is actually a beast in the sense that its primitive is surprisingly complicated, involving arcsin and artanh (for example) in combination with square roots. If Anna show us some effort, so will I...

Comment: http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=%281-x%29%5E%281%2F2%29%2F%28x%5E%281%2F2%29%2Bx-a%29&random=false